# Customizable Colors For The Windows "Minimize Maximize, and Close" Buttons

Tags: visual-studio

Ok, this isn't an error, more, I wanna know if this is possible, so, I am making a custom browser in visual studio 2019, I want to customize it like chrome is here is a [image of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31dj6.png)

```java
private void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate(textBox1.Text);
}
```

which is some of my actual code

Edit: If anyone actually had the samequestion, directly doing it for one application is near impossible, you can recreate the titlebar, and use images with around the same size for buttons, use an onClick event, and change the image on hover to get a hover color or effect.

Answer (score 0):

Title bars (which contains the max,min,close buttons) are in the Operating System itself. You can change it globally by [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=21&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiBu5ujt7HkAhXMaN4KHRmcBxsQFjAUegQIABAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.howtogeek.com%2F222831%2Fhow-to-get-colored-window-title-bars-on-windows-10-instead-of-white%2F&usg=AOvVaw2q5GObd4h1IVg8plOv_zOz). But it will change every title bars in all windows application, except for one thing.

That is if that Windows application is not using the title bar.

The point is, instead of title bar, hide it and make your own title bar. Ofcourse make your own Minimize, Maximize, Close buttons (just like what's in the Chrome).